# ASP Core .NET 6 MVC asp- TagHelpers not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm working on a project. Converting a Core 2.1 to .NET 6. It's going pretty well. I noticed that taghelpers are not working. We use a lot of Anchor tags. Every time I search it comes up that I need to add the line

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

to my *_ViewImports.cshtml*. But it is in there and always has been. Intellisense doesn't recognize the taghelpers either. According to the .net6 [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0) it is still part of .NET 6. When I check the Nuget packages I can install *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers* but it has a .NET version of 2.0. So I doubt I should install that.

Any idea's how to get these taghelpers working again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers 2.2 and they work fine. The package has a NETStandard library. This means its backwards compatible.

`>= 2.2.0` means any version *above* 2.2.0

Comment: Ah ok. That is good to know. I installed it and now its working. I am confused tho that I have the framework in my project file like this: <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />. And when I expanded it it shows the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers as part of it. Thats why I assumed I didn't need to add the nuget package and something else is wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't need to install that package, it was built against a really old version of ASP.NET Core (from 2018) and won't receive bug fixes or security updates. This package (and a lot of others) are bundled with the runtime since version 3 so that is why you didn't find newer ones on nuget. I have tag helpers working without adding any extra packages in several projects projects on .NET 6 so while this seems to fix it, it shouldn't be the preferred solution.